# How do you determine which theme you are on when ZSH_THEME="random"

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I found a theme I like but only after executing a program on the command line with a lot of output, so I don't know the name of the current theme!

Here is the relevant part of my .zshrc:

```
# Set name of the theme to load.
...
ZSH_THEME="random"
```

Is there a way to determine which theme I am on?

Comment: According to [`oh-my-zsh.sh` line 85](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/980528f9fa33780499d625bbbb8ea2cada78530d/oh-my-zsh.sh#L85), just `print $RANDOM_THEME`.

Comment: You are correct! .oh-my-zsh/themes/nanotech.zsh-theme ftw! Add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: In the default omz `zshrc` you can find info on `random`: `# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to [`oh-my-zsh.sh` L81-87](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/980528f9fa33780499d625bbbb8ea2cada78530d/oh-my-zsh.sh#L81-87):

```sh
if [ "$ZSH_THEME" = "random" ]; then
  themes=($ZSH/themes/*zsh-theme)
  N=${#themes[@]}
  ((N=(RANDOM%N)+1))
  RANDOM_THEME=${themes[$N]}
  source "$RANDOM_THEME"
  echo "[oh-my-zsh] Random theme '$RANDOM_THEME' loaded..."
```

Therefore you should be able to print the path to the random theme with

```sh
print $RANDOM_THEME
```

Comment: Is it possible to autocomplete `Random_Theme` as it is with `zsh_theme`?

Comment: With `Mac` autocomplete works for `echo $Random_Theme`

Answer (score 15):

As it was requested to its developers team, a new command is added to support this functionality:

just use:

```
echo $ZSH_THEME
```

the response will be the current theme which is using by user.

Comment: This does not help here. The question is which theme is used when `random` as `zsh_theme` is used. I doubt that `zsh_theme` was introduced in 2021. I think it was already available when this question was asked with `echo $ZSH_THEME`.

Answer (score 7):

To update the answer of @4a1e1.

The current version of oh-my-zsh has implemented a second option ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES that works together ZSH_THEME

When

```
    ZSH_THEME="random"
    ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=("robbyrussell" "rkj-repos")
```

To each new terminal opening, only robbyrussell or rkj-repos themes will be applied.

Answer (score 6):

In updated versions you can list the current theme using `omz theme list`. It will list the current theme as well as the available themes for oh-my-zsh.

```
io :: ~ % omz theme list                                                                                                                                                                  
Current theme: flazz

Custom themes:
example

Built-in themes:
3den                    Soliah                  adben                   af-magic                afowler                 agnoster                alanpeabody
amuse                   apple                   arrow                   aussiegeek              avit                    awesomepanda            bira
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `prompt -c` which will print the current theme.

**note**: I am not sure from which version this is available, mine is `zsh 5.8`